# Dragging a globe in D3

Tags: d3.js, projection

By far the most elegant way to rotate a globe in d3 that I've seen is Jason Davies' version: https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/

Unfortunately his code is minified, and even if I un-minify it, I can't make heads or tails of it with all the variables and functions named with single letters.  (It doesn't help that the page includes code to implement "naive" rotation, and also the zooming, which I don't need.)

Anybody know of a demonstration of this technique that doesn't obfuscate the code?

Comment: Had similar problems I use http://planetaryjs.com it uses d3

Comment: Are you looking for an example of a draggable globe or are you interested in that particular technique used by Jason Davies?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a draggable globe that works the same way in terms of UX, even if the underlying code is different.  I don't want the "naive" implementation Davies demonstrates.

Comment: @DavidRea The code used by Jason Davies seems to implemented by his [d3.geo.zoom](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/31168147b88a1748bc8b/) plugin. Although there are numerous copies around with a proper attribution to Mr. Davies, I have never found his original source code. Keep in mind though, that this is D3 **v3** and will not be compatible with v4!

Comment: @DavidRea Furthermore, searching google for *"d3js drag globe"* brings up scores of good examples ranging from trivial ones to the tremendous [*earth*](https://earth.nullschool.net) for which you will even find the [source code](https://github.com/cambecc/earth/tree/master/public) publicly available.

Comment: @DavidRea http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2012/06/24/creating-the-earth-with-d3-js/, http://techslides.com/d3-globe-with-canvas-webgl-and-three-js, http://techslides.com/demos/threejs/globe.html

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you for great resources!  That d3.geo.zoom is exactly what I need (it looks strangely familiar...I'm just used to seeing it with single letters for variables and function names!).

Answer (score 2):

Try looking here: http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5994804. The only thing is that you need to start dragging on a land and not on a water.

You may disregard text in Russian (the code has comments in English), but you may also consider translating it and the linked article.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution for my SvelteKit project, other than the reactive statements most of it can be reused in other frameworks. Also, here is a [live demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/579ef1d1610e4a4dab0ad21d31482913?version=4.1.1).

```
<script>
    import { geoOrthographic, geoPath } from 'd3-geo';
    import { drag } from 'd3-drag';
    import { json } from 'd3-fetch';
    import { select } from 'd3-selection';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { feature, mesh } from 'topojson-client';

    // Map setup & rendering
    let projection = geoOrthographic();
    let path = geoPath().projection(projection);
    let rotation = [0, 0, 0]; // Initial rotation
    let sphere = { type: 'Sphere' }; // Globe Outline
    let land, borders;

    // Reactive code to update on map dragging
    $: if (projection) {
        projection.rotate(rotation);
        path = geoPath().projection(projection);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the rotation of the globe when the user drags on the map
     *
     * @param event
     */
    function dragged(event) {
        const dx = event.dx;
        const dy = event.dy;
        const currentRotation = projection.rotate();
        const radius = projection.scale();
        const scale = 360 / (2 * Math.PI * radius);

        rotation = [
            currentRotation[0] + dx * scale,
            currentRotation[1] - dy * scale,
            currentRotation[2]
        ];

        projection.rotate(rotation);
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        // Geo Data from World-Atlas
        const world = await json('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json');
        land = feature(world, world.objects.land);
        borders = mesh(world, world.objects.countries, (a, b) => a !== b);

        const globe = select('.globe-path');

        // Define drag behavior
        const dragHandler = drag().on('drag', (event) => {
            dragged({ dx: event.dx, dy: event.dy });
        });

        // Apply the drag behavior
        dragHandler(globe);
    });
</script>

<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 960 960" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <!-- Globe outline with transparent fill to make it completly draggable -->
    <path d={path(sphere)} fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" stroke="#000" class="globe-path" />

    <!-- Land Outline -->
    <path d={path(land)} fill="none" stroke="#000" />

    <!--Countries' Borders -->
    <path d={path(borders)} fill="none" stroke="#000" />
</svg>
```